# Nodejs, soap, callback is not a function

Tags: node.js, soap, soap-client

first i got pfx certficate which a exported it to pem and key with openssl (if this could be an issue). I trid to use client.setSecurity(new soap.ClientSSLSecurit ()) but then i get client undefined.

my code goes like this:

```
var soap = require('soap'),
    fs = require('fs');
var url = 'tes.com';

var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer("user" + ":" + "password").toString("base64")



soap.createClient( url, {wsdl_options: {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert/certificate.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('cert/certificate.key')
    }
}, { wsdl_headers: {Authorization: auth} }, function(err, client) {


    client.describe();

});
```

I am getting this error and do not know what is wrong:

```
callback(err, wsdl && new Client(wsdl, endpoint, options));
    ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at D:\web\mobile\node_modules\soap\lib\soap.js:50:5
    at D:\web\mobile\node_modules\soap\lib\soap.js:33:16
    at D:\web\mobile\node_modules\soap\lib\wsdl.js:2167:9
    at Request._callback (D:\web\mobile\node_modules\soap\lib\http.js:114:14)
    at self.callback (D:\web\mobile\node_modules\request\request.js:187:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Request.onRequestError (D:\web\mobile\node_modules\request\request.js:813:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

tnx
miha

Comment: I got this issue because I was calling `await` on the non-async function.. `await client.getXX` instead of `await client.getXXAsync`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your arguments is not correct. Please correct like this :

```
soap.createClient( url, {wsdl_options: {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert/certificate.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('cert/certificate.key')
    },
wsdl_headers: {Authorization: auth} }, function(err, client) {


    client.describe();

});
```

Comment: Thx for this :) I fixed it but now getting:

<code>  client.describe();
              ^
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'describe' of undefinedat D:\web\mobile\app.js:26:8
    at D:\web\mobile\node_modules\soap\lib\soap.js:50:5
    at D:\web\mobile\node_modules\soap\lib\soap.js:33:16
    at D:\web\mobile\node_modules\soap\lib\wsdl.js:2167:9
    at Request._callback 
</code> 



How to know where is the issue? How to do debugging if the issue is with certificate or someting else? tnx

Comment: @user2017319 Check the `err` object

Comment: tnx @Ebrahim Pasbani for you quick replys.
this is what error shows: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1007:11) at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1030:20) at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14) 25 Aug 10:07:36 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..

Is this reagrding ssl or someting else? tnx

Comment: @user2017319 It says timeout exception. So check if that host is open for port 443 or not and if it's reachable or not

Comment: see it :) I talked with client and they said that the timeout on our side should be around 1 min for the first time (their web service behavior). Is it possible to set this on soap.createClient ? I can not set this on callback as client in callback is not defined due to timeout. tnx

Comment: @user2017319 Add `connection: 'keep-alive'` to `wsdl_headers`. Maybe it works

Comment: @user2017319 If that does not work please try this : `Keep-Alive: timeout=60, max=120`

Comment: @user2017319 If the main question is resolved please kindly accept my answer